# How many audio channels does a macbook pro(2015) jack have?

Tags: audio, macbook-pro, headphone-jack

I have a 7.1 sound system in my house! Does my Macbook Pro support 7.1 channels?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am going to say **no**. This is based on the [specifications](http://www.apple.com/uk/macbook-pro/specs-retina/) of the MacBook from the Apple website.

> **Audio**
>
> Stereo speakers
>
> Dual microphones
>
> Headphone port
>
> Support for Apple iPhone headset with remote and microphone
>
> Support for audio line out (digital/analog)

Traditionally headphone ports are stereo only due to the fact standard humans only have two ears.

Comment: The digital line out is TOSLINK optical, which can do a multichannel digital bitstream.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially, but it depends on how you are trying to do this.

Without knowing your exact model, and looking at the specifications [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP719?locale=en_US), you do have DisplayPort which can output 7.1 audio.

It looks like the machine also has digital audio out, which is a more useful connector, however I believe this would only carry up to 5.1.